# Read txt file by searching for a word and also retrieve the lines of the found word and also count the lines of the found word - Possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368778/read-each-line-of-a-txt-file-by-looking-for-the-first-word-at-the-beginning-of-e) I posted a question but I still stuck

Is my txt:

```
Toto1 The line
Toto2 The line
Toto3 The line
Toto2 The line (second)
Toto3 The line (second)
...
```

When I search "Toto2" it would be necessary to recover each line which contains "Toto2" and also it would be necessary to count the number of line that contains "Toto2", is it possible?

`var regex = new RegExp('Toto2.*\n', 'g');`

With this we would have to return this:

```
Toto2 The line
Toto2 The line (second)
```

and from other variable:

```
2
```

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a simple regex:

```js
const text =
`Toto1 The line
Toto2 The line
Toto3 The line
Toto2 The line (second)
Toto3 The line (second)`;

const filteredLines = text.split('\n').filter(line => /Toto2/gi.test(line));

const count = filteredLines.length;

console.log(filteredLines);
console.log(count);
```

Getting lines with respective line number (with the help of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))

```js
const text =
`Toto1 The line
Toto2 The line
Toto3 The line
Toto2 The line (second)
Toto3 The line (second)`;

const linesWithIndexes = text.split('\n').reduce((all, line, i) => {

    return all.concat(/Toto2/gi.test(line) ? {line, lineNumber: i + 1} : []);

}, []);

console.log(linesWithIndexes);
```

Comment: thank you it works well, do you know if it is possible to recover the number of the line here: line => /Toto2/gi.test(line)?
  2 = "Toto2 The line",
  4 = "Toto2 The line (second)"

Comment: @jacke yes, I've updated the snippet. `linesWithIndexes` returns the array of lines and their numbers (as objects)

Comment: Oh thank you, it's quick answers on this site and always well explained. I will test tonight.

Comment: @jacke ++. If it's fine, please mark it as resolved ;)